# return to menu after playing a video in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to return to the menu after I play a video in unity. This is my code:

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {
        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("Cinderella.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);

    }

function Update () {

}
```

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer below since it fixed your problem. Do **not** edit your question only to ask a new question not relating to your old problem. When you accept that answer below, you can create a **new** question. *I have reversed your question to the original text it had*

Comment: I tried to create a new question but it says that I have to create a question after 90 minutes.

Comment: Then wait 90 minutes. Once you get your reputation up, you can ask [more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask) questions easily. So, don't do that. Here is how to accept [Hellium's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Happy coding!

Comment: I don't have network connection after 90 minutes.

Comment: You get 2 points each time you accept. At some point you will be able to ask more questions. Come back later. Its the rule and I did not set it. it applies to every one.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` "pauses" the execution of your Unity application, you can load the menu scene right after the call to this function :

```
#pragma strict
import UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

function Start ()
{
     Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("Cinderella.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
     SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" exactly? If you want precise answers, bring precise details to your problem. Have you any error in the console ? Have you put some `Debug.Log` to check if the scene manager is called ?

Comment: The scene is not opening. I didn't put debug.log.